# Why node.js v12.0.0 process 32+ bit numbers another way?

Tags: node.js, numbers, v8, 32-bit

```
$ nvm use 11.15.0 && node -e 'console.log(9876 ** 5 % 4321)' && node -p process.versions.v8
Now using node v11.15.0 (npm v6.7.0)
1341
7.0.276.38-node.19

$ nvm use 12.0.0 && node -e 'console.log(9876 ** 5 % 4321)' && node -p process.versions.v8
Now using node v12.0.0 (npm v6.9.0)
441
7.4.288.21-node.16
```

Whats changed, why node.js now process big numbers another way?

Comment: My be linked with this change https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/27078/files

Comment: Not linked, built v12 with that commit reverted, still 441

Comment: Why would this have anything to do with 32-bit integers or Smis? There are no integers involved here, only floats.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with 32 bits as a limit/boundary of anything.

You can see the true result of 9876 ** 5 if you use BigInts:
`9876n ** 5n === 93951865167752549376n`
That result has more bits than a 64-bit float, i.e. a JavaScript `Number`, can store. So when you use Numbers for the computation, you get:
`9876  ** 5  === 93951865167752560000`
Which is a value that's rounded to the maximum precision that a `Number` can store, which includes a rounding error.

In [this commit](https://crrev.com/98453126c109016c9d32c6ebd89dd83f69dd8efb), V8 changed how it computes exponentiation of doubles. The new implementation, based on fdlibm, is generally considered very good; in case of this particular computation it ends up rounding differently from the old implementation (which produced `9876  ** 5  === 93951865167752540000`). I'm not sure whether any of them is generally better on average; at any rate the JavaScript spec allows "implementation-defined rounding".

**Takeaway: when your `Number`s get big, be aware that the last bits might be rounded off.** For many use cases that doesn't matter, and floating-point behavior is a great fit. You just can't rely on `% 4321` giving correct results. (Neither "1341" nor "441" is correct, they're just different rounding errors. The correct mathematical result of (9876 ** 5) % 4321 is 2140.) If you need bit-for-bit precision of large integers, use BigInts.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know that was rounding error, question was why it different. So now I know, thanks